# Can We Change Wavelengths of Electromagnetic Waves by Interacting them with Each Other?

Tags: light, physics

Can we convert radio waves into light by making the radio waves interact with each other to produce visible light?

Comment: Photons do not (ok there are some gamma rays that do) interact with each other.

Comment: I've actually done this before, I put metal in a microwave and it started to glow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electrical design or EM equations.

Comment: @laptop2d that's the radio waves interacting with the metal and the air and then the air producing visible light.

Comment: If I can gamma ray interactions, I'd think I would be able to understand what is going on in a microwave. I do know how microwaves work, the comment above was a late night attempt at scarasm

Answer (score 1):

No. At a very fundamental level, electromagnetic waves do not interact with each other. They only interact with charged particles, mainly electrons.

You can get some effects that affect the frequency of a wave by interacting it with a nonlinear material. For example, you can produce green light by passing light from an IR laser through a frequency-doubling crystal.

But what we normally think of as "radio waves" have wavelengths that are many, many orders of magnitude longer that the wavelengths of light. Meters or centimeters vs. nanometers.

Any followup questions should probably be posted to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That statement is not true in general. For example, inside an optical material if the intensity of the beams is high enough the beams may undergo scattering through some non-linear effects.

Comment: @dirac16: Isn't that what I said? But the waves are not interacting with *each other*, they're interacting with the material through the absorption and re-emission of photons.

Comment: There is one special case: gamma rays can interact with each other to produce fermions, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics but that is beside the OP's question